# Laravel/Octobercms eager load relation with one record

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I am having a Main table "devices"
each device has a oneToMany relation with "devicelogs"

Device Model

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public $hasMany = [
        'devicelogs' => 'Myhome\Myplugin\Models\Devicelog'
    ];
}
```

DeviceLog Model:

```
class Devicelog extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = [
        'device' => 'Myhome\Myplugin\Models\Device'
    ];
}
```

I want to eager load devicelogs relations with only one record in response with latest log for that relation.

I've tried doing:

```
$d = Device::with([
    'devicelogs' => function ($query) {
        $query->latest('created_at')->limit(1)->get();
    }
])->get();
```

with this i only get one device with relation devicelogs having one latest record. I want all device with one device log.

I tried following:

```
$d = Device::with([
    'devicelogs' => function ($query) {
        $query->first();
    }
])->get();
```

with this i only get one device with relation devicelogs having one first record.

When I do :

```
$d = Device::with([
    'devicelogs' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at','desc');
    }
])->get();
```

I do get all devices loaded with relations collection in desc order. But issue is i dont want entire devicelogs, I just want latest/last one for each device.

So I tried doing:

```
$d = Device::with([
    'devicelogs' => function ($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(1);
    }
])->get();
```

This again only gets latest/last devicelogs with single record for only one device. rest all devices get empty devicelogs relation.

In record I have atleast 2 or more devicelog for each device.
What i want is to have onely one and last/latest devicelog to return for each device when i run eager loading.

Im not sure where exactly im doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around this which you may benefit from. In Laravel you would simply define a new relation and make it a hasOne.

Since OctoberCMS still has access to use the Laravel style relation methods. You could do something like the following;

in your Device.php model

```php
public function latestDeviceLog()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Myhome\Myplugin\Models\Devicelog')->latest();
}
```

then you can access with.

```php
Device::with('latestDeviceLog')->get();
```